# Runge-Kutta method accuracy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, runge-kutta-methods

I got a Runge-Kutta method here and I solve this system using it.

So here's  Runge-Kutta stuff
\begin{align}
 k_1 &= f(t_n, y_n) 
\\
 k_2 &= f(t_n + h/2, y_n + hk_1/2) 
\\
 k_3 &= f(t_n+h, y_n - hk_1 + 2hk_2) 
\\\hline
 y_{n+1} &= y_n + h(k_1 + 4k_2 + k_3)/6 
\end{align}
where $h$ is step

Here's my test system
\begin{align}
 y'_1 &= -5y_1 - 10y_2 + 14e^{-x} 
\\
 y'_2 &= -10y_1 - 5y_2 + 14e^{-x} 
\end{align}
with exact solution  $y_1(x) = y_2(x) = e^{-x}$

**UPD:** The initial condition here is $y_1(0) = y_2(0) = 1$

I need to solve it on $[0;4]$.

---

Well, I thought I solved it right, because I checked how the exact solution and these approximate solution plots looks like (on the left, on the right I zoomed plot until saw difference)
[image: plot and zoom]

Also I checked how the plot of the difference between exact solution and approximate solution depending on step (let's call it `e/h`) looks like.

So $e/h$ it looks like this
[image]

But when I checked `e/h^4` dependence it looked like these
[image]

I showed it to the teacher and she said that my solution is wrong, it's not suppose to be like these! I show my code to her asked for help but she said that she doesn't understand matlab :c

Have I really done something wrong? And if yes what I've done wrong? And if not how to prove that I'm right?

Here's my code btw

Runge-Kutta method

```
  function [ res_y ] = RungeKutta(dim, size, grid, step, f1,f2,y1, y2)
   
    k1=zeros(dim);
    k2=zeros(dim);
    k3=zeros(dim);
    
    h = step;
    
    res_y(1,1) = y1;
    res_y(2,1) = y2;
    
    for i=1: size

       k1(1)= f1(grid(i),y1,y2);
       k1(2)= f2(grid(i),y1,y2);

       k2(1)= f1(grid(i)+h/2, y1+h*k1(1)/2, y2+h*k1(2)/2);
       k2(2)= f2(grid(i)+h/2, y1+h*k1(1)/2, y2+h*k1(2)/2);

       k3(1)= f1(grid(i)+h, y1-h*k1(1)+2*h*k2(1), y2-h*k1(2)+2*h*k2(2));
       k3(2)= f2(grid(i)+h, y1-h*k1(1)+2*h*k2(1), y2-h*k1(2)+2*h*k2(2));

       res_y(1,i+1) = y1 + h*(k1(1) + 4*k2(1) + k3(1))/6;
       res_y(2,i+1) = y1 + h*(k1(2) + 4*k2(2) + k3(2))/6;

       y1 = res_y(1,i+1); 
       y2 = res_y(2,i+1);
    end

 end
```

Main method

```
    a = 0; b = 4;
    h = 0.1; % step
    t = a:h:b; %grid
    n = 2; 
    m = size(t,2);
    
    
     hold on;
         plot(t, exp(-t),'b-')
         plot(t, exp(-t),'r--')
     hold off;
    
    y1=1; y2 = 1;
    
    f1_ptr = @f1;% out = -5 * y1 - 10 * y2 + (14)*exp(-x);
    f2_ptr = @f2;% out = -10 * y1 - 5 * y2 + (14)*exp(-x);
    
    res_y = RungeKutta(n,m-1,t,h,f1_ptr, f2_ptr,1,1);
    
    hold on;
    plot(t,res_y);
    
    hold off;

%e/h and e/h^4 plots

 fig_a = figure;
set(fig_a,'name','e/h','numbertitle','off')
hold on;


counter = 0;


for h=0.001:0.01:0.1
    y1=1; y2 = 1;
    t = a:h:b;
    m = size(t,2);
    counter = counter + 1; 
    
    result_appr = RungeKutta(n,m-1,t,h,f1_ptr, f2_ptr,y1,y2);
    result_exact = exp(-t);
    
    
   result_difference = abs(result_appr(1, :) - result_exact);
    
    e1(counter) = max(result_difference);
    e2(counter) = max(result_difference);
    
    hh = h*h*h*h;
    
    ehh1(counter)=e1(counter)/hh;
    ehh2(counter)=e2(counter)/hh;  
    
       
end;
   
h=0.001:0.01:0.1;
    plot(h,e1,'c');
    plot(h,e2,'c');
hold off;



fig_b = figure;
set(fig_b ,'name','e/h^4','numbertitle','off')

hold on;
    plot(h,ehh1,'r')
    plot(h,ehh2,'b')
hold off;
```

f1 function

```
function [ out ] = f1( x, y1, y2, alpha, beta )
if nargin == 3
    alpha = 5;
    beta = 10;
end

out = -alpha * y1 - beta * y2 + (alpha + beta - 1)*exp(-x);

end
```

f2 function

```
function [ out ] = f2( x, y1, y2, alpha, beta )
if nargin == 3
    alpha = 5;
    beta = 10;
end
out = -beta * y1 - alpha * y2 + (alpha + beta - 1)*exp(-x);

end
```

Comment: Where are the initial conditions?

Comment: @Amzoti oops sorry, I'll update question

Comment: @Amzoti I updated it!

Comment: I dont read Matlab code but, in the statement : "res_y(2,i+1) = y1 + h*(k1(2) + 4*k2(2) + k3(2))/6;" is it "y1" or "y2" ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it's 'y2'

Comment: @DanilGholtsman. When you have such a problem, after a few hours, you are no more able to see anything. In this case, ask a friend to look at it. Trust me, I starting in computing sciences 53 years ago. Does this change your results ? Please reply and post. Glad to have been able to help (hoping that this is the case).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici 53 years ago? wow sir, you're awesome!
Btw I changed this line `res_y(2,i+1) = y2 + h*(k1(2) + 4*k2(2) + k3(2))/6` but it changed nothing. Well, my firends in university always asking me for help. Actually here in my town and in coutry our CS education nowadays it's not good, as you can see :)

Comment: @DanilGholtsman: Are those supposed to be $e^{-t}$ instead of $e^{-x}$ terms? Also, over the range you defined, wouldn't the numerical solution have issues? It is okay over $[0,1]$, for example.

Comment: @Amzoti well, actually $t$ is array of the points where we execting our function. $e^t$ and $e^x$ are equal thing. What kind of issues? Over [0,1] approximation looks okay too

Comment: Why does your teacher say that your solution is wrong ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo because she says that plot of `e/h^4` not suppose to look like it looks like here

Comment: And how should it look ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo she said that first point are too far from X axis ($>500$)

Comment: The code seems right. From the type of the plot I could think of a problem depending on the finite precision of the machine arithmetic, but matlab uses double precision by default. In fact the phenomenon happens if one forces lower precision with small steps. You could tell to your teacher ...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo well, I tried once (I told her about it but I wasn't sure, I mean I didn't want to made research so it were sound like an excuse maybe). Colud you please write an answer then?

Comment: In the meanwhile let me know if you are studying from a textbook.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo no, no textbooks. Just lectures.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I guess tommorow I ask other numerical methods teacher to check what I've done wrong

Comment: I need to know where the test about $e/h^4$ comes from for a **third** order Runge-Kutta method: can your teacher give you some written reference ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo haha, guess what? I showed(and translared) her this post (and the previous one too) and the answers today! And she agreed that I'm not suppose to check $\frac{e}{h^4}$ and etc, so I guess everything is ok now! Thank you :)

Comment: @TonyPiccolo hi! could you write what you've said as answer. I know it's been a while lol but I realized that nobody still wrote anything and your suggestuion were right thou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is a classical [third-order method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675436/intuitive-understanding-of-third-order-runge-kutta-method) as computed and presented by [M. Wilhelm Kutta in 1901](https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog/page/440/mode/2up), based on the Simpson quadrature rule.

This means that the global error will scale like $h^3$ and the local truncation error like $h^4$.

Plotting the error as computed against $h$, but in a loglog plot and for a geometric sequence of step sizes, `for h = 10.^[-4:0.5:-1]`, gives a line that has a very nice slope $3$.

[image]

Another way to visualize this is to plot the difference of the computed to the exact solution divided by $h^3$. This gives an error profile plot

[image]

that nicely and visually converges to the leading coefficient $c(x)$ in $e(x)=c(x)h^3+O(h^4)$. Note that this is the absolute error, and that the solutions fall exponentially to zero, which explains that the error falls in the end. In a plot of the relative error one could expect the curve to continue to grow away from zero.

Comment: Oh, after 7 years I don't even understand what it was about what I was writing in the question. As a student I knew math a bit, but years of web development washed out almost all stuff from uni completely...

But nice to see that the answer is here :)